# If $A$ has eigenspace of dimension bigger than 1, then $\{v, Av, \dots, A^{n-1}v\}$ is linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Problem.**
Suppose $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$ is such that $A$ has an eigenspace of dimension bigger than one. Prove that for any $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ the vectors $v, Av, \dots, A^{n−1}v$ are linearly dependent.

---

**Solution Attempt.**
Let $E_\lambda$ be the eigenspace which has dimension bigger than one. Then there exist linearly independent vectors $x_1, \dots, x_k \in E_\lambda$. Extend these to a basis $\beta = \{x_1, \dots, x_k, y_1, \dots, y_{n-k} \}$. Let $Y = \text{span }(y_1, \dots, y_{n-2})$. Then $V = E_\lambda \oplus Y$. Also, $A$ is $E_k$ invariant. The idea from here is to write $v = x + y$ where $x \in E_k$ and $y \in Y$. Then, for each $i$, $A^{i-1}v = A^{i-1}x + A^{i-1}y = \lambda^{i-1} x + A^{i-1} y$. And lastly, consider the set $\{y, Ay, \dots, A^{n-1}y\}$. If each $A^jy \in Y$, then we have proved the result. Which leads to my question...

---

**My Question.** Is $A$ necessarily invariant on $Y$? I think no. (Which is why I'm here!) And if not, then I must be missing some important conclusion. Any hints?

Comment: what does an eigenspace dim bigger than 1 tell you about the minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Consider the quotient space $\bar V \colon = \mathbb{C}^n/E_{\lambda}$. Since $E_{\lambda}$ is invariant by $A$, there is an induced linear operator $\bar A$ on $\bar V$ by $\bar A \bar v= \overline{ A v}$.  Now, let $m = \dim \bar V$. We have $m < n-1$. So for every $\bar v \in \bar V$, the vectors $\bar A^{k} \bar v$, $0\le k \le n-2$ are linearly dependent. That means: for every $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$, there exists a linear combination
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \alpha_k A^k v \in E_{\lambda}$$
Now conclude
$$(A-\lambda) (\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \alpha_k A^k ) v = 0$$