# $v,Tv,\dots,T^{n-2}v$ is Linearly Dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Denote the dimension of $V$ as $n$. Suppose that $V$ has an eigenspace of dimension at least 3. Let $v \in V$. Prove that $(v,Tv,T^2v,\dots, T^{n-2}v)$ is linearly dependent.

I'm not quite sure where to go with this. I have thought about looking at a direct sum decomposition of $V$ into the aforementioned eigenspace and some other subspace of $U\leq V$, but it doesn't seem to be fruitful because $U$ is not necessarily invariant under $T$.

Comment: If $T$ = 0, then the set is definitely linearly dependent

Comment: Ah, misread the claim as "independent."

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243000/if-a-has-eigenspace-of-dimension-bigger-than-1-then-v-av-dots-an-1v?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you let $U_k = \mathrm{span}_{\mathbb C} \{v,T(v),\ldots, T^{k-1}(v)\}$. Now for any $k \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ the set $\{v, T(v),\ldots, T^{k-1}(v)\}$ is clearly already linearly dependent unless $\dim(U_k) = k$. Hence if $\dim(U_{n-2})<n-2$ we are done, so it remains to consider the case when $\dim(U_{n-2}) = n-2$.

Now let $E$ be an eigenspace of $T$ with eigenvalue $\mu$ and $\dim(E)\geq 3$. $\dim(U_{n-2}) = n-2$ and $\dim(E)\geq 3$ implies that $E\cap U_{n-2}$ is nonzero. It follows that there exist scalars $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-3}$, not all zero, such that $w=\sum_{j=0}^{n-3} a_jT^j(v) \in E$. But then applying $T$ we find
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-3} \mu a_jT^j(v) = \mu.w = T(w) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-3}a_jT^{j+1}(v)
$$
or equivalently, setting $a_{-1}=0$,
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-2} (a_{j-1} -\mu a_j)T^j(v) = 0.
$$
Now if $m= \max\{k: 0\leq k \leq n-3, a_k \neq 0\}$, then the coefficient of $T^{k+1}(v)$ in $(\dagger)$ is $a_k$ and hence $(\dagger)$ shows that $\{v, T(v),\ldots,T^{n-2}(v)\}$ is linearly dependent as required.

Comment: I think you mean $\dim(U_k)=k,$ not $k+1,$ since it is the span of $k$ vectors, as defined here.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry yes -- now corrected!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bit better and show that $\big\{I,T,T^2,\dots, T^{n-2}\big\}$ is linearly dependent by proving that $T$ has minimal polynomial degree at most $n-2$, which then implies OP's result.  Let $\lambda$ have algebraic multiplicity $m$ and geometric multiplicity $\geq 3$.

For concreteness we may choose a suitable basis $\mathbf B$ such that
$T\mathbf B = \mathbf B \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
Z_{m} &\mathbf 0
\\ \mathbf 0 &A_{n-m}
\end{array}
\right]$
where $Z_m$ corresponds to the invariant subspace $\ker \big(T-\lambda I\big)^m$ and $A_{n-m}$ corresponds to invariant subspace $\text{image} \big(T-\lambda I\big)^m$.  Per Cayley Hamilton the matrix $A_{n-m}$ is annihilated by its characteristic polynomial $q$, which has degree $n-m$.

We know $\dim \ker \big(T-\lambda I\big)^m = m$ and we have
$3\leq \dim \ker \big(T-\lambda I\big)\leq \dim \ker \big(T-\lambda I\big)^{2}\leq \dots\leq \dim \ker \big(T-\lambda I\big)^{m-2}$
where the inequalities are strict unless $\dim \ker \big(T-\lambda I\big)^{k}=\dim \ker \big(T-\lambda I\big)^{k+1} = m$ (why?).
$\implies \dim \ker \big(T-\lambda I\big)^{m-2}=m$, hence $Z_m$ is annihilated by $p(z)=(z-\lambda)^{m-2}$.

Conclude $p\big(T)\cdot q(T)=\mathbf 0$
$\implies$ the minimal polynomial for $T$ has degree $\leq n-2$.